# convert lists to tuples converting also the lists inside the list

Tags: python, list, type-conversion, tuples

A simple way to convert a list to a tuple in Python is this:

```
tuple1=tuple(list1)
```

But if the list1 contains one or more lists, they remain the same. Is there a way that we can convert them as well?
E.g.

```
list1=[1,3,'abc',[3,4,5]]
```

goes to:

```
tuple1=(1,3,'abc',(3,4,5))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recursion is all you need here:

```
def convert(l):
    return tuple(convert(x) for x in l) if type(l) is list else l
```

```
>>> convert([1,3,'abc',[3,4,5]])
(1, 3, 'abc', (3, 4, 5))
>>> convert([[[[[[]]]]]])
((((((),),),),),)
>>> convert(42)
42
```

Comment: Excellent use of recursion.  It works for any level of nesting (below the recursion limit -- not really an issue).

Comment: I think `isinstance(l,list)` is preferred.

Comment: @mgilson: Wasn't sure. Edited. I'd argue that in this case you probably don't want to convert list-derived classes to tuples.

Comment: If that's the case, I'd suggest using `type(x) is list` just to be more clear that you're dealing with lists and lists only.

Comment: @mgilson: Is that one of the times it's appropriate to us `is`? I'm never sure.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thanks Eric!

Comment: @Eric -- Yes, I think so (as far as it is every appropriate to do a very specific type-check in python ;-).  `is` means that they are the same object.  `==` just means that they're in some sense equivalent (as defined by `__eq__`).  In this case, `is` and `==` do the same thing with the former being more explicit (in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

use `isinstance()` to see if an element is a list or not:

```
In [64]: lis=[1,3,'abc',[3,4,5]]

In [66]: tuple(tuple(x) if isinstance(x,list) else x for x in lis)
Out[66]: (1, 3, 'abc', (3, 4, 5))
```

Comment: Does `list` have any builtin superclasses?

Comment: No it don't, but `type()` might not work for sub-classes of `list`.

Comment: @Eric:  Superclass?  `abc.types.ListType`.  Subclasses, I don't know.